# Why volatile does not solve data race during comparison

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I'm trying to experiment with multithreading and following examples from here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4

I've posted my code below.
Could you please help me to understand why data race happen for "`if (x < y) {`" and not for "`if (y > x) {`" ?

I'm using **openjdk-14.0.1**:

> Linux void-MS-7678 5.4.0-29-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 29 14:32:27 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Code:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataRace dr = new DataRace();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(()-> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
                dr.increment();
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(()-> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
                dr.check();
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    private static class DataRace {
        private volatile int x = 0, y = 0;

        public void increment() {
            x++;
            y++;
        }

        public void check() {
            // System.out.println("x=" + x + " y="+ y); // - NO ISSUES
            // if (y > x) { - NO ISSUES
            // if (x < y) { - ISSUES
            if (x < y) {
                System.out.println("DataRace detected: x < y");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
/home/void/.jdks/openjdk-14.0.1/bin/java -javaagent:/home/void/Development/idea-IC-183.4588.61/lib/idea_rt.jar=46411:/home/void/Development/idea-IC-183.4588.61/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/void/Development/multithreading/out/production/classes Main
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y
DataRace detected: x < y

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `volatile` is about visibility of changes, not race conditions.

Comment: @akuzminykh if I understand this example correctly, there should not be any race condition. We should have out-of-order execution in the increment() method that volatile should solve, however I don't see that it is working as I expect.

Comment: If you make `x`, `y`, `increment`, and `check` `static` (like in the example you linked), does the result change?

Comment: @JacobG. No, it did not help. Here is the code after the change: https://gist.github.com/bff38874/faefc79fbcbc08c30da5edcc1c7caf43

Comment: "data race" is any time you have unsynchronized access to shared variables by more than one thread, and at least one of the accesses is a write.

Comment: tl;dr: because `t1` can increment `y` in between `t2` reading `x` and `t2` reading `y`.

Comment: @JacobG., There is no reason why `static` should change anything. Either way, there are two shared variables. The `static` keyword changes their location in memory, but it doesn't change the fact that they are being shared by two different threads or, the fact that the accesses are unsynchronized.

Comment: @besmirched I'm aware :) I just wanted the OP to replicate the example that they were referencing

Comment: x increments before y.  The variables are changing, even in the midst of x < y or y > x being evaluated.  That can make a difference.  All volatile does is guarantee you see the updated copy.

Comment: Your code will exhibit data races in both "<" and ">" cases.  Their frequency will depend on the VM version.  For example, it exhibited tens of data races on Amazon JVMv8 while at most one data race on Amazon JVMv11 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comparison `if (x < y) {` is not atomic.

- `t2` loads `x` for the comparison
- `t2` stops working
- `t1` increments `x` and `y`
- `t1` stops
- `t2` starts
- `t2` loads `y` for the comparison
- as `x` is the old value and `y` is new, incremented, `x < y` is `true`.

Here is an example of how to solve that with `synchronized`:

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataRace dr = new DataRace();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(()-> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
                dr.increment();
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(()-> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
                dr.check();
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    private static class DataRace {
        private volatile int x = 0, y = 0;

        public synchronized void increment() {
            x++;
            y++;
        }

        public void check() {
            // System.out.println("x=" + x + " y="+ y); // - NO ISSUES
            // if (y > x) { - NO ISSUES
            // if (x < y) { - ISSUES
            boolean xSmallerY = false;
            synchronized (this) {
                xSmallerY = x < y;
            }
            if (xSmallerY) {
                System.out.println("DataRace detected: x < y");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you for "The comparison if (x < y) { is not atomic." and really good example. That's totally make sense now.

Answer (score 1):

akuzminykh already [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61648339/1398418) why `if (x < y)` can be true. You also asked why you never see the same phenomenon when you do `if (y > x)`.

The reason is that in java expressions are always evaluated from left to right and when you do `y > x`, `y` is always going to be loaded from memory first so `x` was already incremented before `y` and if `x` is going to be read from a subsequent iteration it's also going to be larger than `y`.

You can still see "DataRace detected" being printed when you do `y > x` but that can happen if and only if `x` is close to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and it overflows and becomes negative in subsequent iterations after `y` was read from memory and only then `x` is being read from memory.

```
public class Check {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataRace dr = new DataRace();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
                dr.increment();
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
                dr.check();
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    private static class DataRace {

        private volatile int x,y;

        public void increment() {
            // to make sure the race condition is caused by the ++ and not by the assignment
            synchronized (this) {
                x = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                y = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            }
            x++;
            y++;
        }

        public synchronized void check() {
             if (y > x) {
                 System.out.println("DataRace detected: y > x");
            }
        }
    }
}
```